# Science visualization tool for arbitrary 3D objects

Tags: data-visualization, scientific-computing

I'm simulating interactions between non-spherical particles and looking at the output with VMD. Unfortunately, VMD's visualization options are quite limited when it comes to collections of non-spherical objects. The same goes for all the other science visualization software I've seen.

What I'm looking for is a tool that can take a set of coordinates and quaternions and render some high-quality predefined models at each coordinate with the right orientation. I need a minimum of learning overhead (I really don't want to learn OpenGL to do this). Bonus if it can take a series of such data and use it to construct animation frames. Is there anything out there that can do this?

Comment: Do you have a preference in operating systems?

Comment: Linux, but windows is also ok.

Comment: This is too vague to be answerable. What sort of non-spherical objects? It sounds like you want to write to a file and then view renderings offline (write file and view render in separate phases) but you also mention OpenGL so I'm not sure. Google turns up a [posting](https://www-s.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/mailing_list/vmd-l/20279.html) to the VMD mailing list regarding rendering ellipsoids but it looks like it doesn't come "batteries included".